# rbenv multiple invocations of constants - how to drop proper ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rbenv

The following warnings are issued when rails runs commands linked to the server or database connections

```
/Users/dd/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::VERSION
/Users/dd/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/version.rb:10: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
```

So there is a duplication of these invocations (they are very numerous on one machine).  `rbenv` and `bundler` are the only constants I can pick up...

I have no idea how they came about.  I want to gt rid of them as they make running tests tedious...

What is the safest course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [issue on the budler repository](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3068) illustrates the problem, its development and solution.  Maybe the thread is so long it hurts the indexing...

Immediate solution, update to a version of bundler:

```
gem update --system 3.0.8
```

You'll actually get a scroll of previous definitions and see the for the last time.